# Maven doesn't look for dependency in all configured repositories

Tags: maven

I have 5 repositories. Two are defined in settings.xml and three in my root/pom.xml. I want Maven to download myArtifact from repositoryNumber4.

I have a mirrow configured like this:

```
<mirror>
<id>mirrowId</id>
<mirrorOf>*,!repositoryNumber1,!repositoryNumber2,!repositoryNumber3,!repositoryNumber4</mirrorOf>
<name>some description</name>
<url>repositoryNumber5</url>
</mirror>
```

While building the project in debug mode, Maven writes the following log:

```
[DEBUG] Verifying availability of C:\myProject\myArtifact.jar from [repsitoryNumber1(repsitoryNumber1Url, releases+snapshots), ..., repsitoryNumber4(repsitoryNumber5Url, releases+snapshots)]
```

This indicates to me, that Maven is aware of all 5 repositories.

Directly after the "verifying availability" message, I get the this error message:

```
Failure to find myArtifact in repositoryNumber1Url
```

And that's it. The log doesn't indicate, that Maven tries to search in repositoryNumber4. What could cause Maven to only look in one repository to resolve this dependency?